# "has been" vs "have been"

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I am answering an online English grammar test and encountered the following question

> Where was Jack yesterday? —I don't know. He ***_*__*_*____** seeing the doctor.

My answer is: *might has been*
Correct Answer is: *might have been*

Why not *might has been*? *He* is singular?

Comment: "He might have seen", surely, unless he's having an affair with the doctor, or went more than once.

Answer (score 14):

Because the verb is "might". After the first verb you use the infinitive, for example:

> He *has* something.
>
> He might *have* something.

The same rule applies when using "have" to indicate past tense. I will **bold** the conjugated verbs in the following examples. The following verbs are in infinitive forms.

> He **is** sick.
>
> He **has** been sick.
>
> He **might** have been sick.

Comment: This is actually a pretty bad answer as the modalness of 'might' is the source of the most interesting part of the question, and I didn't address it. Too lazy to fix.

Answer (score 13):

*Might* is an auxiliary (modal) verb (it's actually the past tense of *may*), and those always require the following verb to be in infinitive form. Other examples of this are *can/could* and *shall/should*. (Which is why the (in)famous "I can has cheezburger" strikes us as ungrammatical: the correct form would be "I can have..." – or actually, since it's a question, "Can I have...")